# How can i allocate bandwidth among users more than given rate?

Tags: bandwidth

if i have limit the amount of bandwidth among all users lets say for 2mbps for each. But if there is more bandwidth available how can i let users have more bandwidth like 7 mbps or 8 mbps for particular type of traffic (using tc)?